# Showing menus in multiple activity in android

Tags: java, android

I have a Listview,when i click on the list it shows the details part,in that activity it **shows 3 menu option Details,Party and Attachment**.When i click on details it should show the same details part.After i click on Party it shows list of parties and again whn i click on menu it shows 3 menu option Details,Party and Attachment and clicking on details menu should show the same details part.
Is that possible, plz help me out.

Comment: I suggest you work on your question (use the 'edit' link at the bottom). Please try to limit the question to what you need to be done programatically.

Comment: actually images are not getting posted.otherwise i would hav shown with images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to make 3 Activities with the same menu, you can make a abstract base Activity that implements the menu and then extend that with your 3 concrete Activities.

```
public abstract class ActivityWithMenu extends Activity {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // add your code here
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // add your code here
    }
}
```

Then in another Acitivity class, you can create the 3 different activities, something like:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends ActivityWithMenu {
    // add your implementation here - the menu will already be taken care of in the base class
}
```

This way, you have 1 common menu for 3 activities.  I hope that helps.